# What is the proper syntax for using a property setter as a selector argument in Swift 2.0?

Tags: properties, swift2

I'm trying to pass a computed property's setter as a selector argument and I'm unsure of the syntax in Swift 2.0.

Here's some example code I've tried:

```
class Baker: NSObject
{
    var cookie: String
    {
        get
        {
            print( "Returing \( _cookie ) cookie." )
            return _cookie
        }
        set
        {
            print( "Setting cookie to \( newValue )." )
            _cookie = newValue
        }
    }

    private var _cookie = "butterscotch"

    func delayedCookie()
    {
        self.performSelector( Selector( "cookie:" ), withObject: "vanilla", afterDelay: 0.0 )
        self.performSelector( Selector( "setCookie:" ), withObject: "peanutbutter", afterDelay: 0.0 )
    }
}

var baker = Baker()
baker.cookie = "chocolate"
baker.delayedCookie()
//  expected cookie to == "vanilla" or "peanutbutter"
baker.cookie
//  cookie == "chocolate"
```

Comment: As of Xcode 7, beta 4 I believe you can. See this: http://ericasadun.com/2015/07/24/beta-4-we-want-more-swiftlang/ . Also I'm not too worried about the performSelector specifically, I need this for Undo code, but I used perform selector because it's easy to make a quick example.

Comment: Yes, I just confirmed you can use the performSelector calls in the beta 4 of Xcode 7 in a playground (give it a try) as long as the object inherits from NSObject. Here is the quote: "• The performSelector family of APIs is now available for Swift code. (17227475)" source: http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7_beta_4/Xcode_7_beta_4_Release_Notes.pdf

Comment: awesome! time for Apple to update the docs  :)  thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is Selector( "setFoo:" ) for computed property "foo". The test code was failing in my playground due to the delay not the syntax of the selector argument.

```
class Baker: NSObject
{
    var cookie: String
    {
        get
        {
            print( "Returing \( _cookie ) cookie." )
            return _cookie
        }
        set
        {
            print( "Setting cookie to \( newValue )." )
            _cookie = newValue
        }
    }

    private var _cookie = "butterscotch"

    func cookieFunction()
    {
        self.performSelector( Selector( "setCookie:" ), withObject: "peanutbutter" )
    }
}

var baker = Baker()
baker.cookie = "chocolate"
baker.cookieFunction()
baker.cookie
//  cookie == "peanutbutter" as expected.
```